# Simplify nested loops function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two arrays of data, one containing a list of movies and one various movie genres.
I want to create a new array combining the data of those two. I need to match the genre_ids of the first one with the ids of the second. The new array will have all the information the movies array already have plus a new field containing the genre names (from the second array). I have managed to do it but I guess there is a better and less complex way. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

**Initial arrays**

```
const movies = [
 {
   genre_ids: [1, 2, 3],
   id: 1,
   title: 'Title One',
 },
 {
   genre_ids: [1, 3, 5],
   id: 2,
   title: 'Title Two',
 },
 {
   genre_ids: [3, 4, 5],
   id: 3,
   title: 'Title Three',
 },
];

const moviesGenres = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Comedy',
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Action',
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Horror',
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   name: 'Fantasy',
 },
 {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Western',
 },
];
```

**Result array**

```
const newMoviesArray = [
  {
    genre_ids: [1, 2, 3],
    genre: ['Comedy', 'Action', 'Horror'],
    id: 1,
    title: 'Title One',
  },
  {
    genre_ids: [1, 3, 5],
    genre: ['Comedy', 'Horror', 'Western'],
    id: 2,
    title: 'Title Two',
  },
  {
    genre_ids: [3, 4, 5],
    genre: ['Horror', 'Fantasy', 'Western'],
    id: 3,
    title: 'Title Three',
  },
];
```

**Current implementation**

```
const getMoviesWithGenres = (movies, movieGenres) => {
  const newMoviesArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(movies));
  for (const movie of moviesCopy) {
    const movieGenreIds = movie.genre_ids;
    const genreItems = [];
    for (const genreId of movieGenreIds) {
      for (const genre of movieGenres) {
        if (genre.id === genreId) {
          genreItems.push(genre.name);
        }
      }
    }
    movie.genres = genreItems;
  }
  return newMoviesArray;
};
```

Comment: If you have a working solution, you might be able to get better answers from [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map over the movies and [**array.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter over `moviesGenres` along with [array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which searches for the match id's index and then you could get the names of matching genre by map method and merge it to the original movie like `{...movie, genre}` .

**Working Example:**

```js
const movies = [
 {
   genre_ids: [1, 2, 3],
   id: 1,
   title: 'Title One',
 },
 {
   genre_ids: [1, 3, 5],
   id: 2,
   title: 'Title Two',
 },
 {
   genre_ids: [3, 4, 5],
   id: 3,
   title: 'Title Three',
 },
];

const moviesGenres = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Comedy',
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Action',
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Horror',
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   name: 'Fantasy',
 },
 {
   id: 5,
   name: 'Western',
 },
];

const newMoviesArray = movies.map((movie, index) => {
  const matchedGeneres = moviesGenres.filter(({id, name}) => movie.genre_ids.indexOf(id) !== -1);
  const genre = matchedGeneres.map(({name}) => name);
  return {...movie, genre}
});

console.log(newMoviesArray);
```

Comment: @MavrosGatos, Glad to help you.